# Writing records into a .dbf file using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, dbf

I'm currently building a web-app which displays data from .csv files for the user, where they are edited and the results stored in a **mySQL** database.

For the next phase of the app I'm looking at implementing the functionality to write the results into ** existing .DBF** files using **PHP** as well as the mySQL database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't DBF a format of Microsoft Access? How's that related with MySQL?

Comment: I need to be able to write back into this file format for the client. The mySQL database will still be written into, but the results will also be written to .DBF files too. 

Edit - Before down-voting, at least wait for a response to your question.

Comment: So writing in MySQL is one thing and writing in Access is a completely separate thing. See http://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Comment: @Qualcuno - .dbf used to be dBase and FoxPro, nothing to do with Microsoft

Comment: Not absolutely certain, but look at the [dBase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php) extension

Comment: I just found this, this could be the solution!

http://dbf-software.com/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a third route which I should have thought of before, and is probably better for what you want. PHP, of course, allows two or more database connections to be open at the same time. And I've just checked, PHP has an extension for dBase. You did not say what database you are actually writing to (several besides the original dBase use .dbf files), so if you have any more questions after  this, state what your target database actually is. But this extension would probably work for all of them, I imagine, or check the list of database extensions for PHP at http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php. You would have to try it and see.

Then to give an idea on how to open two connections at once, here's a code snippet (it actually has oracle as the second db, but it shows the basic principles): 
http://phplens.com/adodb/tutorial.connecting.to.multiple.databases.html
There's a fair bit of guidance and even tutorials on the web about multiple database connections from PHP, so take a look at them as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard kind of situation in data migration projects - how to get data from one database to another. The answer is you have to find out what format the target files (in this case the format of .dbf files) need to be in, then you simply collect the data from your MySQL file, rearrange it into the required format, and write a new file using PHP's file writing functions.

I am not saying it's easy to do; I don't know the format of .dbf files (it was a format used by dBase, but has been used elsewhere as well). You not only have to know the format of the .dbf records, but there will almost certainly be header info if you are creating new files (but you say the files are pre-existing so that shouldn't be a problem for you). But the records may also have a small amount of header data as well, which you would need to write to work out and each one in the form required.

So you need to find out the exact format of .dbf files - no doubt Googling will find you info on that. But I understand even .dbf can have various differences - in which case you would need to look at the structure of your existing files to resolve those if needed).

The alternative solution, if you don't need instant copying to the target database, is that it may have an option to import data in from CSV files, which is much easier - and you have CSV files already. But presumably the order of data fields in those files is different to the order of fields in the target database (unless they came from the target database, but then you wouldn't presumably, be trying to write it back unless they are archived records). The point I'm making, though, is you can write the data into CSV files from the PHP program, in the field order required by your target database, then read them into the target database as a seaparate step. A two stage proces in other words. This is particularly suitable for migrations where you are doing a one off transfer to the new database.

All in all you have a challenging but interesting project!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot what .dbf files were for. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your swift, robust and in-depth response! The CSV idea is definitely something I will be looking into. I came across this article in the last hour, which shows how to insert directly into a .dbf file through mysql this could be the solution? - http://dbf-software.com/sql-insert.html

Comment: Ah, you've already found it. Yes, it shows dbf files in use; PHP can connect to that kind of database; see my new answer that I've added.